# Resources to learn about quantum optics lab experiments?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

I would like to improve my knowledge of quantum theory by learning indepth about different quantum optics lab experiments.

I would like to find textbooks / resources which give an indepth knowledge and understanding about the following topics:

1. generation of entangled photon pairs and single photons
2. single photon detection techniques and measurement of photon entanglement
3. ghost imaging
4. single photon interference

My end goal is to know enough to fully understand recent scientific articles on these topics.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262850/2451 and links therein.