# Quantum statistics of light - literature

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

I would like to request recommendations for good textbooks, theses, or papers that discuss the topic of quantum statistics of light, covering aspects such as stochastic properties and squeezed states. Additionally, I would appreciate suggestions for source material focusing on experimental methods in this field. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262850/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Optical Coherence, and Quantum Optics" by Mandel and Wolf.

It has it all.