# Book Recommendation

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-optics, education

I am a first year PhD student and I am going to work in Quantum Optics ahead in my PhD. I am right now undergoing my coursework and I want to read the subject from the scratch to build a good theoretical background required for my research ahead. I am confused among various books to start with like Christropher Gerry & Peter Knight , G S Agarwal Quantum Optics, Scully & Zubairy Quantum Optics or may be Mark Fox Introduction to Quantum Optics. Please recommend me some text that would fulfill my need and that is written with modern notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book Recommendation: Quantum optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262850/)

Comment: It does but there is a huge list of books and it is not possible to go through all of these. I want one or two books and stick to them for the fundaments of the subject if there are any such books.

Comment: The comment by @Ghorbalchov is entirely appropriate.  It is not possible to recommend books for individuals as one cannot know the details of your background  and preparation.  The best textbook for you is the one *you* will like best.  The recommendations have enough discussions for you to pare down the list.